# Delete DynamoDB string attribute with golang expression package

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm having trouble deleting an attribute of a dynamodb item using the `UpdateItem` command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/expression/#Builder.WithUpdate

```
    expr := expression.Set(
        expression.Name("my_attribute_a"),
        expression.Value(""),
    ).Set(
        expression.Name("my_attribute_b"),
        expression.Value(""),
    )

    update, err := expression.NewBuilder().
        WithUpdate(expr).
        Build()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to build update expression: %v", err)
    }

    input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        TableName:                 &ddb.emailAccountTableName,
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  update.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: update.Values(),
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "id": {
                S: &id,
            },
        },
        UpdateExpression:       update.Update(),
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: aws.String(dynamodb.ReturnConsumedCapacityTotal),
    }
    fmt.Println(input.String())
    result, err := ddb.svc.UpdateItem(input)
```

The result of running the above is:

```
{
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    #1: "my_attribute_a",
    #0: "my_attribute_b"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    :0: {
      NULL: true
    },
    :1: {
      NULL: true
    }
  },
  Key: {
    id: {
      S: "38zqtaNezbB8eZw4pbJKm7"
    }
  },
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
  TableName: "my-table",
  UpdateExpression: "SET #0 = :0, #1 = :1\n"
}
```

And the result is the attributes for the item get set to `true`. I want the attributes to be removed. I've tried using `nil` but that has the same result, and `expression.Null` just sets the string to the value `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use `expression.Remove` instead of `expression.Set` here's the relevant update:

```
expr := expression.Remove(
    expression.Name("my_attribute_a"),
).Remove(
    expression.Name("my_attribute_b"),
)

update, err := expression.NewBuilder().
    WithUpdate(expr).
    Build()
```

Which results in the following:

```
{
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    #0: "my_attribute_a",
    #1: "my_attribute_b
  },
  Key: {
    id: {
      S: "qfsphqt37ELyn2BanwE2fd"
    }
  },
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
  TableName: "my-table",
  UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #0, #1\n"
}
```